# jquery $("id") returns empty array when the id is present in another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
search_select = e.id + "";
$("#" + search_select).toggleClass("sub-services-color");
```

The `$("#" + search_select)` returns object with `[]` but when the id is on the page it returns the entire tag

```
<li class="select-services" id="exterior_chimney" onclick="app.coreservices.selectSubServices(this);">
    <div class="services-position">
        <div>Chimney Installation & Repair</div>
        <div class="hide-logo">

        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Your question is seriously not specific enough for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: When the element with the ID is in the page it returns the entire element, but when it isn't, it returns an empty jQuery object. This is by design. Did you have in mind for it to work in any other manner?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or share more of your code

Comment: when i click the li on the page the sub-services-color class is added but i am    using search and when i click from another page i wont added

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it would be better to use

```
$("body").on("click touchstart", ".select-services", function(e){
  $(this).toggleClass("sub-services-color");
});
```

Comment: sorry this is my first question on stack and i dont know how to post properly

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a sample example for the toggleclass - may be not exact match and it not very clear what exactly you want..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        $("li").toggleClass("main");      
    });
});
```

```css
.main {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="select-services" id="exterior_chimney" onclick="app.coreservices.selectSubServices(this);">
    <div class="services-position">
        <div>Chimney Installation & Repair</div>
        <div class="hide-logo">

        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: what i want is actually  how to get the id of another page through jquerry

Comment: id of whom.. ? can you be more specifc - provide example / code

Comment: thanks all of you for the help but i managed to get the id by getting it afterShow